# Angular: how to make a "search" take you to another route and display results?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a main page with a nav, and each nav option takes you to another route. It all looks like a single page app, but each "page" has it's own route and controller.

My problem is that I want to put a search box in the navbar. When someone uses the searchbox, I want to take the user to the "search" route and then display the results. I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out these two issues:

1. Where do I store this "searchbox" logic? E.g. when someone searches, they choose the type of search from a dropdown, then the search query in the inputbox. I have special logic to automatically choose which dropdown value based on the value typed in the inputbox.
2. How do I redirect to the
   "search" route and display the results based on the input from the
   previous page?

It's probably clear I'm a newby to Angular. I'm happy to work out the details, but I'm mainly looking to understand *how to structure* the solution to this problem. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You have two fairly large questions jammed into one question here;  on their own, each one of these questions would be a full topic in a blog or a tutorial; together, this question is just too broad to be handled adequately, which means if you do receive any answers, they will barely scratch the surface of anything useful.

Comment: in a *very broad* sense, this sounds like a candidate for a directive, along with a unique route/page to display the results.

Comment: Thanks Claies, I didn't realize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I love about Angular the most is the amount of options you can apply.

Your goal can be reached either by using a service. A service is a singleton class which you can request from controllers. Being a singleton what ever value you store in the service is available to all controllers. You can than either $watch for value change, use $broadcast to notify data change or use $routeParams to send data with route change.

A service is built as follows :

The following assume you have a global module var named 'app'

```
app.service('myService', function(){

     var myValue;

     this.getMyValue = function(){
        return myValue;
     };           

     this.setMyValue = function(value){
        myValue = value;
     };
});
```

Then you request a service from a controller like you request an angular service such as $scope.

```
app.controller('myController', ['$scope', 'myServce', function($scope, myService){

    $scope.myValue = myService.getMyValue();

    //Example watch
    $scope.$watch('myValue',function(){
       //Search criteria changed!!
    }, true);

}]);
```

Angular is terrific..have fun coding

Answer (score 1):

Basically you would want an own state for your search page, so this is where we begin (I expect you to use the ui-router and not Angulars built in router):

```
.state('search', {
    url: "/search",
    templateUrl: "pages/search.html",
    controller: 'SearchController as ctrl',
    params: { searchString: {} }
})
```

As you can see, I've defined an additional parameter for the search string that is not part of the URL. Of course, if you like, you could change that and move the parameter to the URL instead:

```
.state('search', {
    url: "/search/:searchString",
    templateUrl: "pages/search.html",
    controller: 'SearchController as ctrl'
})
```

The actual search input is pretty straight forward as well, because it's only HTML:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="searchString" on-key-enter="ctrl.goSearch(searchString)">
```

The function for the state change has to be placed in the controller for the primary template (e.g. the controller of your navigation bar if the search is located there):

```
var vm = this;
vm.goSearch = goSearch;
function goSearch(searchString) {
    $state.go('main.search', { searchString: searchString });
}
```

Of interest is also the on-key-enter directive that I've added:

```
angular.module('your.module')
    .directive('onKeyEnter', OnKeyEnter);

function OnKeyEnter() {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind("keydown keypress", function (event) {
            if(event.which === 13) {
                scope.$apply(function (){
                    scope.$eval(attrs.onKeyEnter);
                });
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    };
}
```

On pressing the enter-key, it will call the function you supply as attribute value. Of course you could also use a button with ng-click instead of this directive, but I think it simply looks better.

Last, but not least, you need a Search Controller and a HTML template for your search page, which I won't give to you, as it is up to you what you display here. For the controller, you only need to know how you can access the search string:

```
angular.module('your.module')
    .controller('SearchController', SearchController);

SearchController.$inject = ['$scope', '$stateParams'];

function SearchController($scope, $stateParams) {
    $scope.searchString = $stateParams.searchString;

    /* DO THE SEARCH LOGIC, e.g. database lookup */
}
```

Hope this helps to find the proper way. :)